# Add Zoom to a Grouped Bar Chart that uses a scaleBand

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use rescaleX on a scaleBand to add zoom functionality to a Grouped Bar Chart.

```
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on("zoom", () => { zoomed() });

...

function zoomed() {

    var t = d3.event.transform;
    var x0t = t.rescaleX(this.x0);
    var x1t = t.rescaleX(this.x1);

    ...
}
```

But `t.rescaleX(this.x0)` doesn't work on a scaleBand, how can I apply zoom functionallity to a scaleBand?

Here is a full codepen [Grouped Bar Chart](https://codepen.io/medeirosrich/pen/OvNLep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by changing the zoomed function to:

```
function zoomed() {

  var t = d3.event.transform;

  // redefine the x0 domain range with the event transform scale (k)
  x0.range([0, width * t.k]);

  // transform .barGroup using redefined domain range and event transform params
  g.selectAll(".barGroup")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x0(d.State) + t.x) + ",0)scale(" + t.k + ",1)"; });

  // apply transform to .axis--x and call xAxis
  g.select(".axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + t.x + "," + (height) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
}
```

Full codepen [here](https://codepen.io/medeirosrich/pen/Wzwjzp)

**Update:** 
A better method of zooming a scaleBand bar chart by Mike Bostock (non-grouped) 
https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-zoomable-bar-chart

**Update 2:** 
Updated Grouped bar chart zoom function:

```
function zoomed() {
  x0.range([0, width].map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));
  x1.rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);

  g.selectAll(".barGroup").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });
  g.selectAll(".bar").attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); }).attr("width", x1.bandwidth());

  g.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
}
```

Full Codepen: [here](https://codepen.io/medeirosrich/pen/bvRORN)

Comment: Hi Richard, i m also having the above mentioned problem that rescaleX is not working if my scale is scaleband. Do you know how can i get new scale for x axis in zoom function

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. In this example I modify the x0 range and tansform the scale of the .barGroup element by the same factor. I didn't have much success trying to rescale the scaleBand, and from my research it may not even be possible.

Comment: Bostock says here that it is not possible https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/134